# Is there another resource that shows all possible attributes one can have on an HTML element?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I know I can go directly to the HTML specifications to look up all of the attributes one can have on a tag (custom ones excluded obviously as per html 5). Its easiest(?) with the [HTML 4.0 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html) to do this, but its messy to dig through. The same is true for the HTML 5 spec. What I want is a akin to "cheat sheet" that displays all HTML elements and their possible attributes on a single page.

Are there any other resources that show all of the attributes one can have on a given tag but on a single page without having to drill down or be bombarded with a lot of text and examples?

**EDIT**

I cleaned up my question to be more direct in what I am looking for

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted down. I think its a straight forward question and I edited the question to more precisely state what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!

A list of all html elements and their attributes won't possibly fit on a page, even 2--at least not  on a human readable page!

**[Edited: More cheats! ...]**

http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/html5-cheat-sheet/html5-cheat-sheet.pdf

This is what you want...4 pages.

[image]

Comment: This definitely helps. However, it doesnt show what attributes you can have on these element. Thanks for the resource. Even if it cant fit on one page, make it multiples I can print!

Comment: See edited answer for elements+attributes all on 4 pages...or 2 double-sided pages.

Comment: BOOM! That's what I want! 4 pages it is. See, I just wanted a nice condensed view of all of the elements one can have and what attributes can be applied to them.